# How to do this without a for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have 3 columns:

1. installment
2. interest
3. exposure

1st row goes like this

```
  installment interest exposure

    0          0        1000
```

Installment is 0 for 1st row and a constant figure afterwards. Let it be 100.

Interest of ith row = 0.5% * exposure of (i-1) th row

Exposure of ith row = exposure of (i-1)th row -
                          (installment of ith row - interest of ith row)

```
    installment interest   exposure

    0           0          1000
    100         0.005*1000 1000-(100-5)
```

**interest depends of previous exposure and exposure depends on latest interest**.This should go on till exposure is 0. I have done this using a for loop in R.

is there any other way to do this without a loop. I'm looking for a speedy process?

Comment: Add more example data

Comment: Yes, show us your loop implementation, then people will know what you want, and may be able to suggest speedups and will be able to test them against the original.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the loop version, for those who might be interested in tackling this:

```
n <- 10
# "pristine" starting data, in case you want to try other options.
df_start <- data_frame(
  installment = c(0, rep(100, n)),
  interest = c(0,rep(NA, n)),
  exposure = c(1000, rep(NA, n))
)


df1 <- df_start    
df1 <- within(df1,{
  for(i in 1:n) {
    interest[i + 1] <- exposure[i] * 0.005
    exposure[i + 1] <- exposure[i] - (installment[i + 1] - interest[i + 1])
  }
  rm(i)
})
```

I find that R needs loops in two situations.  There may be more, but these are what I've found so far:

1. When you're performing an action on subset of data, and you need to dynamically decide how big the subset needs to be.
2. When you're performing an action on two or more variables, and they have complex inter-dependencies from row to row.

This is an example of the 2nd case - there is no way to determine the interest in row *n* without knowing the exposure in row *n*-1, and you can't determine the exposure in row *n*-1 without knowing the interest in row *n*-1.  In other words, you really need both data points in the previous rows to get a number row *n*.

If you really need speed, your best bet is to code it in a compiled language, then create a wrapper in R which calls the compiled function - this is what vectorization in R generally means, and this particular function is small enough that it shouldn't be too hard to implement in a compiled language.

Comment: Hi Thanks. But I've implemented something very similar to this. What I wanted to know was if there was a way to do this quicker using some other technique.

Comment: As mentioned by others in the comments, the code was needed as a place to start in terms of thinking about vectorization.  I added it to my answer to save anyone else who wanted to try to find a non-loop solution the time.  As I explained below, I don't personally see a way to avoid the loop in R.